# Difficulties with Rashi on Mishlei 8:23

Tags: tanach, rashi

Rashi quotes a pasuk (נסיכי בני אדם) supposedly from Yechezkel 35, but its really a pasuk from Micha 5:4 (נסיכי אדם) without the word bnei. Is there any explanation (with evidence) for this besides a mistake on Rashi's part?

Comment: A lot of times it's a mistake by a copyist somewhere down the line.